# Создание самоподписанного wildcard сертификата SSL для разработки

Tags: google-chrome, https, ssl

Для локального тестирования сайтов мне нужно, чтобы они открывались по HTTPS на локальном Apache.

Проблема в том, что для каждого нового сайта приходится генерировать свой сертификат, подключать его и импортировать в Chrome, чтобы он считал сертификат доверенным.

Я хочу создать один wildcard сертификат (скажем, *.loc - для всех сайтов вида site1.loc, site2.loc и т. п.), добавить его один раз в Chrome и потом просто для всех сайтов в локальном Apache указывать этот сертификат.

Я создал обычный самоподписанный сертификат, в CN указал "*.loc". Импортировал его в Chrome по [этой инструкции](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate/15076602#15076602). Но когда я захожу на `https://site.loc`, Chrome пишет "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID". С обычными самоподписными сертификатами вида "site.loc" все работает нормально, проблема только с wildcard.

Что я делаю не так? Может, нужно каким-то другим способом создавать сертификат или по-другому импортировать его в Chrome?